# Problem with splitting string into tokens with strtok - Char arrays are empty after splitting

Tags: c, arrays, string, fgets, strtok

I am quite new to programming in C and I have a problem that I have been trying to solve the last days, but now I am at a point where I don't know what to do.

I am reading in a string with the function "input" which gets then split into parts everytime there is a white space. The parts are stored in char arrays, which works fine so far.
However, when I call the next function "checkInput" in main, the char arrays are empty again. What do I have to change, so that the char arrays are not empty when calling the next function?

When I used scanf instead of fgets, it worked. But why?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
void input(char* string1, char* string2, char* string3)                     
{
    char ptr[100];

    printf("Enter String: \n");
    fgets(ptr, 100, stdin);
    printf("%s \n", ptr);

    if(ptr != NULL)
    {
        string1 = strtok(ptr, " \n");
        printf("string1: %s \n", string1);
    }
    if(ptr != NULL)
    {
        string2 = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        printf("string2: %s \n", string2);
    }
    if(ptr != NULL)
    {
        string3 = strtok(NULL, " \n \0");
        printf("string3: %s \n", string3);
    }
}

int main(void)
{

    char string1[100];
    char string2[100];
    char string3[100];
    input(string1, string2, string3);
    checkInput(string1, string2, string3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that I have to pass the char arrays by reference? Like `void input (char** string1, char** string2, char string3**) ` ?

Comment: We need the correct definitons of the functions used in `inputCheck()`, like f.e. `IsOperator()`. I found some references but they seem to be meant for C++, not for C.

Comment: @FrüchteTony If you want to "ping" a user who is not the OP, you need to set `@username` in front of your comment.

Comment: @Yunnosch What parameters are wrong especially?

Comment: What happens to `char ptr[100];` when `input()` returns? (hint: `ptr` is part of the `input()` function's function-stack which is destroyed (released for re-use) on return). Since `strtok` will be returning an address within `ptr` to the start of each token -- your strings will point to memory that is no longer valid after the function returns. If you used `scanf ("%99[^\n]", ptr);` instead of `fgets(ptr, 100, stdin);` and you say *"it works"* -- welcome to the world of *Undefined Behavior*...

Comment: Additionally, in `main()`, you declare `char string1[100];`, then in `input()` you attempt to assign the pointer from `strtok` to a **copy of** the pointer from `main()`, e,g `string1 = strtok(ptr, " \n");`. This won' work. The copy of the pointers from `main()` already point to valid storage, so you could do, e.g, `ptr = strtok(ptr, " \n"); if (ptr != NULL) strcpy (string1, ptr);` and copy the token to the storage already declared in `main()`.

Comment: *When I used scanf instead of fgets, it worked.* - You mean `scanf("%100s",ptr);` instead of `fgest(ptr,100,stdin);`? - By the way you should do it rather `99` instead of `100` characters to save the storage place for the terminating `\0`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough about the scanf function. I didn't use ptr with it. I wrote the strings directly into string1, string2 and string3.

Comment: However, it is working now. I changed it like David C. Rankin suggested and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help! This problem was really giving me headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declare `string1, string2, string3` in `main()` as arrays of 100 characters each with *automatic storage duration*, the storage is already provided for the arrays in `input()`. The easiest thing to do to get the strings back in `main()` and avoid the problem with storage for `ptr` in `input()` becoming invalid on return is simply to `strcpy` the tokens to your strings in `input()`, e.g.

```
void input(char* string1, char* string2, char* string3)                     
{
    char ptr[100], *p = ptr;

    printf ("Enter String: \n");
    fgets (p, 100, stdin);
    printf("%s \n", ptr);

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        p = strtok (p, " \n");
        if (p)
            strcpy (string1, p);
        printf("string1: %s \n", string1);
    }
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        p = strtok (NULL, " \n");
        if (p)
            strcpy (string2, p);
        printf("string2: %s \n", string2);
    }
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        p = strtok (NULL, " \n \0");
        if (p)
            strcpy (string3, p);
        printf("string3: %s \n", string3);
    }
}
```

Now `string1, string2` and `string3` will remain valid until you exit `main()` and your program is over.